# C# user control crashing VS11

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, crash, controls

I'm finding myself coding C3 for the first time, and using Visual Studio for the first time in a looong time.

I'm creating a user control that allows for picking a file/folder etc, for making that kindof control easier to implement in the future. However whenever I drag the control unto any form, Visual Studio crashes instantly. I have tried rebuilding the entire solution several times.
The error seems to only happen when creating public variables in the control...

Does anyone know how to get around this?
Code is work in progress.... ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BackupReport.tools
{
    public partial class pathchooser : UserControl
    {

        #region "Datatypes"
        public enum DLG { Folder, FileSave, FileOpen };
        #endregion

        #region "public properties"
        public DLG Dtype
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Dtype;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Dtype = value;
            }
        }

        public string labelText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.labelText;
            }
            set
            {
                this.labelText = value;
                label1.Text = this.labelText;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Constructor"
        public pathchooser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Dtype = DLG.Folder;
            this.labelText = "Source:";
            label1.Text = this.labelText;
        }
        #endregion

        private void browse_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (this.Dtype)
            {
                case DLG.Folder:
                    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        path_textbox.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
                    }
                    break;

                case DLG.FileSave:
                    break;

                case DLG.FileOpen:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
also I'm not sure it matters, but I'm using VS11 beta.

//Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public DLG Dtype
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Dtype;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Dtype = value;
        }
    }
```

You have a property referring to itself, and thus calling its own getter and setter inside (respectively) the getter and setter. Something more appropriate would either be to either have empty accessors:

```
public DLG DType{get; set;}
```

or to have accessors referring to private variables:

```
private DLG dtype;
public DLG Dtype
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dtype;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dtype = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice... Did the trick...
now it's just complaining about the public string, says "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct" How is that? 
Accoridng to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx It should be kist fine...

Answer (score 3):

I think your properties are causing a `StackOverflowException` because the getters and setters invoke themselves in an endless loop (Dtype -> Dtype -> Dtype ...).

Try this code instead:

```
private string labelText;

public DLG Dtype { get; set; }

public string LabelText 
{
  get { return this.labelText; }
  set
  {
    this.labelText = value;
    label1.Text = value;
  }
}
```